# What is the difference between TVM and LLVM?

Tags: machine-learning, clang, llvm, apache-tvm

i cant visualize the full software stack  ( pytorch + clang + TVM + LLVM + Hardware .... ) Do you have to have llvm if you use TVM ? do both make optimization ? is there a different functionality for wither one and they need each other or its just different flavor ?